# Asp.net dynamically add an user control

Tags: c#, asp.net

How I can dynamically insert an user control to a master page?

Comment: You want to dynamically add a control to the master page? For all pages of the site? From logic where - in the master page's code behind, or somewhere else?

Comment: Can you please provide more information, are you using ASPX web forms, MVC.  At what level do you want to insert the control from.  Are you in the master page or the child page, or even another control?

Answer (score 3):

```
Control myControl = LoadControl("MyControl.ascx");

Controls.Add(myControl);
```

The only issue with this is you cannot control where it will place this.
If you do want to control where the user control is placed add a place holder control to the page and then do:

```
myPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(myControl);
```

Comment: A good open response to an open question

Comment: @Paul Hadfield - You get what you paid for.  Works a treat too.